# Trying to fix my function

Tags: python, loops

I'm working on a function where I have to return a tuple where the first parameter is a str of the highest number and the second parameter is a list of int. Here's the example and what I wrote for the function:

> > > voting(['G', 'G', 'N', 'G', 'C'])
> > >           ('G', [1, 3, 0, 1])
> > >           """

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733220/python-list-voteg-g-n-g-c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map the position of the maxvalue to the correct party:

```
parties = ['NDP', 'Green', 'Liberal', 'CPC']
winning_party = parties[total.index(max(total))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Counter` to count how many votes each element got. For example:

```
from collections import Counter
...
vote_count = Counter(votes_list)
int_list = vote_count.values() # value is [1, 3, 1]
winners = vote_count.most_common() # value is [('G', 3), ('C', 1), ('N', 1)]
```

As you can see, `Counter` has an interface to both give you the vote count for each element, and give you all the elements in descending order of votes.