# python list vote(['G', 'G', 'N', 'G', 'C'])

Tags: python

```
vote(['G', 'G', 'N', 'G', 'C'])
```

I want to get this result : `('G', [1, 3, 0, 1])`

```
g_count = 0
n_count = 0
l_count = 0
c_count = 0
for i in range(len(ballots)):
    if ballots[i] == 'G':
        g_count += 1
    elif ballots[i] =='N':
        n_count += 1
    elif ballots[i] == 'L':
        l_count +=1
    else:
        c_count += 1

return [n_count,g_count,l_count,c_count]
```

how do i get the 'G' at the front?

Comment: How do you propose to handle ties? And a `dict` looks like what you want here.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732496/trying-to-fix-my-function ?

Comment: If you search for [GREEN NDP CPC](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=GREEN+NDP+CPC) -- names of Canadian political parties (and I'm guessing the "L" here stands for "Liberal") -- in StackOverflow, you see many questions a lot like this, probably because some prof somewhere assigns voting questions involving things like Borda counts in Python as a beginner assignment.

Comment: http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc108h/winter/assignments/a2/handout/index.shtml

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
In [9]: from collections import Counter

In [15]: def vote(lis):
   ....:     c=Counter(lis)
   ....:     return c.most_common()[0][0],[c[x] for x in "NGLC"]
   ....: 

In [16]: vote(['G', 'G', 'N', 'G', 'C'])
Out[16]: ('G', [1, 3, 0, 1])

In [17]: vote(['G', 'G', 'N', 'G', 'C','L','L'])
Out[17]: ('G', [1, 3, 2, 1])

In [18]: vote(['G', 'L', 'N', 'G', 'C','L','L'])
Out[18]: ('L', [1, 2, 3, 1])
```

here `c.most_common()` returns `[('G', 3), ('C', 1), ('N', 1)]`, from this you can get the `'G'`.